# Killing spinor equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, supersymmetry, spinors, supergravity

The Supersymmetry transformation is:

$$\delta \psi_\mu^i=(\partial_\mu +1/4 \gamma^{ab}\omega_{\mu ab})\epsilon^i -1/8\sqrt{2}\kappa \gamma^{ab}F_{ab}\epsilon^{ij} \gamma_\mu \epsilon_j$$ 
For the time part, we substitute $\mu$ by $t$ so equation (2) is:

$$ \delta \psi_{tA} = \partial_t \epsilon _A  + \frac{1}{4} \gamma^{ab} \omega_{tab} \epsilon_A - \frac{1}{8} \sqrt{2} \kappa F_{ab} \gamma^{ab} \gamma_t \epsilon_{AB} \epsilon^B =0$$

Automatically since the spin connections I found to be:

$\omega^{0i} = e^U \partial_iU e^0$ and $\omega ^{ij} = -dx^i\partial_jU+dx^j\partial_iU$

Implies that the ${a, b}$ indices in equation (2) should either be ${0,i}$ or ${i, j}$
$$ \delta \psi_{tA} = \partial_t \epsilon _A  + \frac{1}{4} \gamma^{0i} \omega_{t0i} \epsilon_A - \frac{1}{8} \sqrt{2} \kappa F_{0i} \gamma^{0i} \gamma_t \epsilon_{AB} \epsilon^B     + \frac{1}{4} \gamma^{ij} \omega_{tij} \epsilon_A - \frac{1}{8} \sqrt{2} \kappa F_{ij} \gamma^{ij} \gamma_t \epsilon_{AB} \epsilon^B =0$$

From here, I am having difficulty in proceeding. Some papers like http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0608139 see (4.3.27) separate the $\gamma^{0i}$ into $\gamma^{0}\gamma^{i}$.

This is the first time I encounter such problem, I have no idea how to proceed from here in order to find 2 conditions for ERN BH.

Comment: This is a (admittedly very high level) homework question. Please check the homework policy. Specifically, why are you not sure how to proceed?  What conceptual issues are you having?

Comment: @Sean if I continued from where I stopped, this would be:
$$\partial_t \epsilon_A + \frac{1}{4} \gamma^{0i} e^U \partial_iUe^0 \epsilon_A + \frac{1}{4} \gamma^{ij}(-dx^i \partial_jU+dx^j \partial_iU )\epsilon_A -\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{2} \kappa (-\partial_i A_t) \gamma^{0i} \gamma_t \epsilon_{AB} \epsilon^B = 0$$ 

But the final answer written in the book (actually this is not a homework but an exercise I was following) is:

$$\delta \psi_{tA} = \partial_t \epsilon _A +1/2 e^{2U} \partial_i U\gamma^i \gamma^0 \epsilon_A -1/4 \sqrt{2}\kappa e^u \partial_i A_t \gamma^i \epsilon_{AB} \epsilon^b =0$$

Comment: @Sean so how does my equation match the book's, I think there is something I am doing wrong.. That is why I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @beyondtheory: If it is not homework, but an exercise, it can still count as homework under our policies, since it is homework-like questions which don't meet certain criteria that are likely to be closed.

Comment: Okay @JamalS I will read homework policies and see what criteria my question didn't meet with.

Comment: I agree this just about falls under "homework" policy as it's more "check my work" than "conceptual". Still in this case I would err on the side of leaving the question open, and asking if anyone can help OP to figure out how to proceed. I know I can't.

Comment: The issue is that this question is asking nothing more than "how do I proceed?" But I'm sure it could easily be edited into a good question. As Sean said, you should ask something about the concept that's confusing you. If you can find a reference that  shows the steps to this sort of procedure, you could even ask how to justify going from one step to the next. Maybe if you showed that you _very thoroughly_ searched for such a reference, and that it's just not out there, that might change things (no guarantees though).

Comment: @beyondtheory feel free to continue to comment here and we will help you improve your question. When you do wind up editing the question, it might be a good idea to include the equations you put in your first comment on this post, among other things.